# Getting Vendor code 17002 while connecting my client DB via VPN

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting below error while connecting the database of one of my client via VPN. I am using the same n/w for last 2 years, but since Friday I am not able to connect it and getting below error.

**Error:-**
An error was encountered performing the requested operation: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Vendor code 17002

On friday i tried to connect my localhost:8084 to learn few thing, and i guess in this process only i have change some setting coz of while getting this error. If anyone faced same issue in past and know steps to fix it then please help me.

Thanks
Sanyam

Comment: I presume only you know what changed since Friday.

Comment: We cannot guess. You need to do general checks: is target host available, is its port open, is TNS listener running, is Oracle service running etc.